# Navigation bar not displaying correctly when using bootstrap installed by bower

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the navigation bar to work when using the bootstrap installed by the bower package manager.

The articles in the list below the navigation bar are styled by the bootstrap just fine though. At the end I changed the link to the bootstrap css, and then the navigation bar is styled correctly. Anyone knows why this is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Articles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> // works
    // <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> // not working for navbar
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a></div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Articles</h1>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Article One</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Article Two</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Article Three</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">MyTitle</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add bootstrap.min.css instead of bootstrap.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

"bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
It look like they remove "dist/css/bootstrap.css" from bower_components\bootstrap\bower.json

We fix this issue temporary by overrides our project bower.json. for us it work fine. but waiting for some solution from bootstrap.

```
"overrides":{
    "bootstrap" : {
         "main": [
            "less/bootstrap.less",
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
          ]
    }
}
```